# Optimization problem in support vector machine

Tags: optimization, svm

I want to solve the following support vector machine problem
The soft margin support vector machine solves the following optimization problem:

[image]

What does the second term minimize?
What does the first term minimize?
What does xi measure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first one maximizes the margin ( Actally margin formula is 2/W , so here minimizing W/2 is equal to maximizing the margin)
2. The second term minimzes the error from actual class. (In case of where data is not linearly separable, it will try to maximize margin by allowing the border to move with making error on some points), so the second term will decide how much to move border by allowing error.